# How to throw ParseUUIDPipe exception when write UT with jest

Tags: unit-testing, exception, jestjs, graphql, nestjs

I use NestJS GraphQL and use ParseUUIDPipe to validate UUID from args.

My resolver looks like:

```
async updateImage(
    @Args(
      'companyId',
      new ParseUUIDPipe({
        version: '4',
        exceptionFactory: (error) => {
          throw new ValidationException({
            property: 'companyId',
            constraints: {
              isUUID: error,
            },
          });
        },
      }),
    )
    companyId: string,
    @Args('images')
    images: ImageInput[], 
    //some code return
```

I wrote the following unit test:

```
describe('CompanyResolver', () => {

  let resolver: CompanyResolver;

  let companyId;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        CompanyResolver,
        {
          provide: CompanyService,
          useValue: {
            updateImage: jest
              .fn()
              .mockRejectedValue(updateImageRespone),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    resolver = module.get<CompanyResolver>(CompanyResolver);
  });
  
 // test function
it('testFunction throw', async () => {
    let propertyId: "someId";
    const images = [companyImageInput];

    await expect(resolver.updateImage(companyId, images)).rejects.toThrowError(ValidationException);
  });
```

When I run it, it throws the following error:

```
Error: expect(received).rejects.toThrowError()

   Received promise resolved instead of rejected
```

When I debug, the test case does not run into the function on resolver:

```
exceptionFactory: (error) => {
      throw new ValidationException({
        property: 'companyId',
        constraints: {
          isUUID: error,
        },
      });
```

I don't know how to test and run test case into function

```
exceptionFactory: (error) => {
          throw new ValidationException({
            property: 'companyId',
            constraints: {
              isUUID: error,
            },
          });
```

and throw error. When I run the API, it tests OK, but the test case does not run inside the function. How do I solve this?